# Android save custom data in APK

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have developed (Offline) Android app in which i have to save some employee's data into Local SQLITE database, when i send the apk into another andoird phone the data in the database dose not appear due to local storage of both the devices is different.

My goal is to send the data with the apk file to who ever i send the apk. How can i achieve the goal ?

The problem is i do not have the idea of how to do it, or never have done this kind of project before.

Please guide me.

Comment: seriously ? you want "Local" data to be available globally. wow

Comment: Are you kidding right ?

Comment: there is no way. APK can't be modified.

Comment: This is the customer requirement i have posted here only. 

I wonder why people have declared this question as not useful and marked it negative.
Also why \stackoverflow support people like Ali ahsan , mohit kacha.

Comment: @VladMatvienko : thanks for the suggestion. but i have to find any how to make it work , any other idea from your side will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'd use Firabase in your case. It's free, and needs no server from your side. Should match your requirements

Comment: @VladMatvienko : hi, just readed about Firebase. Seems like somewhere I need to implement in my app and check if it works according to my requirements. Will get back to you soon.
if it works then post it as the answer i will mark it for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If Your database is read only - You can use [`raw`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) folder of project for Your `SQLite` database file, than, after `.apk` was installed, copy it, for example to external storage. But if You need changes in database and synchronized data on all devices - You should use only one server-side database.

Comment: Hi I really appreciate your suggestion,Thanks for it. Also thanks for at least giving suggestion other than making fun like some other people have done it in the comments.

As the customer requirement i have received is the reason why i can not use server side database as it is fully offline app.